# Merge with no conflicts, the code doesn't compile: should I fix it before commit?

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-merge

I'm working with Subversion 1.7.x, and am doing my development on a *branch*.

From time to time I merge from *trunk* to keep the branch up to date.
During the latest merge, though, the incoming code, while totally correct in the *trunk*, doesn't compile in the *branch*.
And that's expected, because the code changed in the *trunk* has partially been rewritten in the *branch* several revisions ago.

Notice that the merge operation completed cleanly, there were no conflicts.
For the sake of clarity, when I say *merge* I mean the operation that modifies the working copy with code from another branch, no commit involved, i.e. just the `svn merge [source] [dest]`.

Since that *branch* will ultimately be reintegrated to the *trunk*, I guess I have two alternatives:

1. fix the compilation errors before committing the merged code;
2. merge from *trunk*; commit (the merged code without edits); edit the code to fix the compilation issues; commit again (i.e. fix the compilation issues subsequently, performing a new, separate commit).

If I edit the merged code before committing it (i.e. I go with #1), will those changes be lost when reintegrating the branch?

Comment: Good question, though it's primarily opinion based and will probably be closed.  Might be a better fit for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Hmm... not as I intended it: I'm worried whether the edits pre-commit would be kept when reintegrating... I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk  when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @PatrickQuirk if a question is primarily opinion-based here, the same applies at Programmers (we have the same close reason). Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**. That being said, I am not sure this question is _primarily_ opinion-based. A group of experts would likely reach a consensus.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to Programmers.SE, except that it would be closed as a duplicate over there of [Is it good idea to require to commit only working code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/119784/is-it-good-idea-to-require-to-commit-only-working-code)

Comment: @durron597 Even after my edit (reading the linked question)? Anyway, this is not a question about best practices...

Comment: @watery I do not think it is opinion based. I think it is a good, answerable question, I just think it would be a duplicate if it were migrated. If you don't think it's a duplicate then feel free to edit how it is different. SVN vs CVS is not enough of a difference in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: no, changes will not be lost.

A little bit more details.
Reintegration merge differ from 'regular' sync merge, because it copy branch to trunk, so both become identical[1]. It can be expressed as 'apply difference between branch and trunk into trunk(wc)'. Of course reintegrate merge should actually be reintegrate merge. Subversion 1.8 somehow guess, earlier versions require `--reintegrate` argument during merge.

Update:

[1] Actually, I made couple tests and found that result will be identical only if you merge into working copy updated to last synced revision. For example, if you sync trunk 1-100 to branch, then create in trunk 10 more additional revisions, then reintegrate branch into trunk - here can be differences.

I personally prefer sync branch to latest revision in trunk, reintegrate and then compare folders for binary identity. Just in case :)

Comment: Thank you for the useful tips. Yes, I align the branch to the latest trunk before reintegrating too.